# How to know which state value changes in ngrx?

Tags: typescript, angular, ngrx

When I use **ngrx**, if I want to transfer a value to its child component, I am doing like this:

**// parent component**

```
<product1-component [product]="(model$ | async)?.product1"></product1-component>
<product2-component [product]="(model$ | async)?.product2"></product2-component>

this.model$ = Observable
  .combineLatest(
    this._store.select('products')
  )
  .let(ProductsModel());
```

Right now I want to use the value `product1` and `product2` inside of the parent component itself. I am doing like this right now (**is there any better way?**):

```
this.model$.subscribe((model: any) => {
  if (!model) return;
  // Right now here no matter which value changes, it will run.
  // However what I want is:
  // if `product1` changes, do something
  // if `product2` changes, do something
});
```

How can I know which state value changes? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` function of the store returns an `Observable`.
As such, you are then free to use any of the operators available in Rxjs to achieve what you want.

To answer your question what you can do is :

```
const nonNullModel$ = this.model$.filter(x => !!x);

this.product1$ = nonNullModel$.map(x => x.product1);
this.product2$ = nonNullModel$.map(x => x.product2);
```

Keep in mind that every time your `products` state slice changes, both `product1$` and `product2$` will push a new value. 
If you are only interested when the product1 or product2 really changes, you can use the `distinctUntilChanged` operator:

```
this.product1$ = nonNullModel$.map(x => x.product1).distinctUntilChanged();
```

Because this is pretty much what `select` does for you, you could instead write:

```
this.product1$ = this_store.select(x => x.products && x.products.product1);
this.product2$ = this_store.select(x => x.products && x.products.product2);
```

You can now use each stream directly in your template using the `async` pipe the same way you pass the value down to the child component.

```
<product1-component [product]="product1$ | async"></product1-component>
<product2-component [product]="product2$ | async"></product2-component>

JSON representation of my product 1: {{product1$ | async | json}}
```

If you want to do something in the parent component class:

```
this.sub1 = this.product1$.subcribe(p => // Do something with product 1);
this.sub2 = this.product2$.subcribe(p => // Do something with product 2);
```

Note that when you subscribe explicitly (as opposed to using `async` pipe) to an observable, you should take care of unsubscribing when you component gets destroyed.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub1 && this.sub1.unsubcribe();
    this.sub2 && this.sub2.unsubcribe();
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are the hero!! Thank you for this detailed answer!